# Installing GeoNetwork?

Tags: installation, geonetwork

I have installed GeoNetwork using the windows installer, but when i try to open, it displays the error message below:

> Raised exception while initializing resource main-db in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\geonetwork\web\geonetwork\WEB-INF\config.xml. Skipped.
>   Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception:
>   "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)";
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db"
>   [90031-152])
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)"; "C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db" [90031-152])
>   Provider        jeeves.resources.dbms.ApacheDBCPool
>   Stack       org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)"; "C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db" [90031-152])
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>    at jeeves.resources.dbms.Dbms.connect(Dbms.java:89)
>    at jeeves.resources.dbms.AbstractDbmsPool.open(AbstractDbmsPool.java:142)
>    at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.initResources(JeevesEngine.java:528)
>    at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.loadConfigFile(JeevesEngine.java:335)
>    at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.init(JeevesEngine.java:192)
>    at jeeves.server.sources.http.JeevesServlet.init(JeevesServlet.java:91)
>    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:477)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:293)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:739)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:254)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:275)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
>    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
>    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
>    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)"; "C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db" [90031-152]
>    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
>    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
>    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:313)
>    at org.h2.store.fs.FileSystemDisk.openFileOutputStream(FileSystemDisk.java:382)
>    at org.h2.store.FileLock.save(FileLock.java:203)
>    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:335)
>    at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:134)
>    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:535)
>    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:218)
>    at org.h2.engine.Database.(Database.java:213)
>    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
>    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
>    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
>    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
>    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
>    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:285)
>    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:114)
>    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:98)
>    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>    ... 49 more
>    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)
>    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>    at org.h2.store.fs.FileSystemDisk.openFileOutputStream(FileSystemDisk.java:374)
>    ... 68 more

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried "run as" Administrator?

Comment: Yes, but no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trying to create the H2 database on "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\geonetwork\jetty\geonetwork.lock.db (Access is denied)". So it seems that you have a privileges problem.

The fastest thing to solve this is to modify the config.xml file to point the database url to another place where you know your tomcat user has writable access.